# How can I interpret the result of percentiles aggregation type

Tags: elasticsearch

I did this query

```
GET /bla bla/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "whatevernameyouwant": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "price",
        "percents": [
          1,
          5,
          25,
          50,
          75,
          95,
          99
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the result

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "whatevernameyouwant": {
      "values": {
        "1.0": 38000,
        "5.0": 50000,
        "25.0": 89999.95904255318,
        "50.0": 135000,
        "75.0": 185000,
        "95.0": 320000,
        "99.0": 800000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what are all these numbers represent please?

I tried to read here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html

but didn't help

the price field has values from 0 until a big number (maybe more than 24000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you are observing in the percentile aggregation results mean that:

- 1% of the prices are smaller or equal to 38000
- 5% of the prices are smaller or equal to 50000
- 25% of the prices are smaller or equal to 89999
- 50% of the prices are smaller or equal to 135000
- 75% of the prices are smaller or equal to 185000
- 95% of the prices are smaller or equal to 320000
- 99% of the prices are smaller or equal to 800000